# How to move mouse cursor on MS Windows with a node.js server?

Tags: windows, node.js, mouse

I need to move the mouse cursor with a node.js server.
The plan is to get the coordinates from an html5 canvas, send those to a node.js server and move a mouse.

Is there a npm module to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also you should post some code illustrating what you have tried if you want to get more responses from SO users. And maybe be a bit more specific as to what you are trying to do if possible. Is there a particular reason as to why you mentioned Windows, what type of application are you trying to build?

Comment: The client side part is done, I will send those coordinates over websockets to a node.js server.
Now, What I want to do is move the mouse. Is there any way to do that? (connect node.js server to Windows Mouse API?)

Comment: How does Windows move the mouse? Has the mouse some kind of actors? Or do you mean via the undocumented WBI (Windows-Brain-Interface) API?

Answer (score 5):

RobotJS will do this!

https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs

There's a beta Windows build avalible and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

You need [Pointer Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Pointer_Lock), which is still experimental and is implemented by very few browsers.

Comment: He ask to move the cursor at the node.js side, not the client side. No need of browser implementations. I think the right answer is Jason Stallings - robotjs

Answer (score 0):

I use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) through a `child_process.exec`, mainly because I have a variety of other things I need to do with the Windows OS and NirCmd does them all (screenshots, kill processes, set volume, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented a npm package for this named [MouseBot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mousebot).

```
import { Bot } from 'mousebot';

let bot = new Bot();

//Move the mouse to the coordinates x=400, y=500. 
bot.mouse.move(400, 500);
```

Feel free to check it out and give some feedback!

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. ```/mousebot/native/index.node: invalid ELF header```